# Codesys V3 and Raspberry Pi SL - How to read values from addresses

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, sensors, i2c, codesys

Good evening.
I have a short question regarding the use of CODESYS Development System V3 and the associated CODESYS Control for Raspberry Pi SL. How do I manage to acquire the values of the connected sensors (e.g. si705x, vcnl) or to write certain bits via the I2C bus? Unfortunately, I cannot find any decisive results or useful documentation for use. With the datasheets of the respective sensors I don't get on either.

Greez

Answer (score 0):

A good worked example, but for another i2c sensor, with code for RPi can be found on [this](http://www.14core.com/wiring-sensiron-shtxx-temperature-sensor-w-d-python/) page. Read/learn from this one and you can build your own.